# Соответствие регулярному выражению для проверки lower_case php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно составить регулярное выражение для текста, с максимальной длиной 6 символов, содержащего только латинские буквы в нижнем регистре, с необязательным разделением символом низжнего подчёркивания (underscore).

Пробовал так:

```
^[a-z_]{1,6}$
```

Но мне также нужно запретить символ "_" в начале и конце строки.

Нужно чтобы:

**Пропускало:**

ex_bar

**Не пропускало:**

_exbar

exbar_

_test_

Пробовал варианты (все не работают):

```
^([a-z]_?[a-z]){1,6}$

^(([a-z]+)_?([a-z]+)){1,6}$

^([a-z](?:_?)[a-z]){1,6}$
```

Comment: `^[a-z][a-z_]{0,4}[a-z]$` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon Спасибо! Работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант из комментария [@archdemon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/31819/archdemon) хороший, но сбивается квантификация `{1,6}` на `{2,6}`.
Что бы разрешить ввод 1 символа, то можно:

- Попробовать использовать негативный просмотр

```txt
^(?!_)[a-z_]{1,6}(?<!_)$
```

- Попробовать использовать логическое или в варианте [@archdemon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/31819/archdemon)

```txt
^(?:[a-z][a-z_]{0,4}[a-z]|[a-z])$
```

- Попробовать использовать позитивный просмотр

```txt
^(?=[a-z])[a-z_]{1,6}(?<=[a-z])$
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и пояснения! Все варианты решают задачу. Только осваиваю регулярные выражения, больше вариантов расширяют понимание